# Seat n people in 4 benches

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle, inclusion-exclusion

> How many ways are there to seat n people in 4 benches so that no bench
>   is left empty with order?

Hints from the teacher

- Each bench should have at least 1 person
- This question is similar to distributing different object among n children
- The answer is one line

I am not sure how to deal with this question, but this was what I tried.

Let $A_i$ be the set of all distributions in which $i-$th bench is empty.

Then $|A_i| = (n-1)^4$ for each $i$.

$|A_i\cap A_j|= (n-2)^4$ for each $i\ne j$

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|= (n-3)^4$ for each $i\ne j\ne k\ne i$

$|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k \cap A_l|= (n-4)^4 = 1$ for all pairvise different $i,j,k,l,m$

Now we are interested in
  $$\Big| \bigcap_{i=1}^n \overline A_i\Big| = \Big|\; \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i}\;\Big|
= n^4-\Big|\; \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\;\Big|
$$We have by PIE:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Big|\; \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\;\Big| &=& \sum_{i=1}^n  \Big|\; A_i\ \Big| - \sum_{i=1}^n  \Big|\;A_i\cap A_j\ \Big|+...\\
&=& 4\cdot (n-1)^4-2n\cdot (n-2)^4+2n\cdot (n-3)^4-4 ..... +0=\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So the final answer is $n^4-$(the above value).

Am I correct, or is there something that I am doing wrong?

Edit: Also maybe I want to apply pigeonhole principle since n items are to be put into m containers, with n > m, then at least one container must contain more than one item..

Comment: What does "empty with order" mean?

Comment: Are the benches distinguishable?  Are the people?  Please edit to include a clear example.  If $n=4$, say, what is the answer?

Comment: How did you obtain the factor $2n$ for the coefficient of $(n - 2)^4$?  What does it represent?

Comment: @NicNic8 no bench is left empty so it means that each bench should have at least 1 person with an order is the seating arrangements.

Comment: @lulu how will people be identical.. Then it is 1 person, ofc they are different as well as the benches. Also, isn't n unlimited number of people since it didn't specify?

Comment: $(n-i)^4$ is the i_th bench to be left empty and maybe I did a miscalculation

Comment: One often works with indistinguishable people.  In that case, a possible answer would be something like "$5$ people sit on bench $A$, $12$ on bench $B$, and so on."   Now, please answer my question about $n=4$.

Comment: Also, do you distinguish between the order on a bench?  if people $X,Y,Z$ are the ones sitting on bench $A$, does it matter if they are ordered as $XYZ$ or $ZYX$ or...

Comment: @lulu haha yes you are right :) It does matter XYZ to ZYX because I want all the possible ways. Thanks! <3

Comment: Please answer the question for $n=4$.  Also do $n=5$ as that case will involve the order issue.

Comment: @lulu I am really sorry, I am not sure but isn't if n = benches = 4 the answer would be 4!?

Comment: $4!$ makes sense...is that what your formula gives?  And what's the answer when $n=5$?  As I say, that's the one where the order issue matters.

Comment: @lulu No clue. Still trying to learn it and only if you help me, I would be able to understand it, and I will be very thankful :)

Comment: You have written an explicit formula.  Just substitute $n=4$ into that.  This is one of the key ways in which examples matter...they give us test cases.  If the formula doesn't give the correct result in explicit examples, then it is wrong.

Comment: Note:  this problem, assuming I have understood it correctly, isn't exactly hard but it involves the use of a standard technique called [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) .  If you are not familiar with that technique, it is unlikely you will discover it on your own.  I'd review some examples of the method before proceeding.

Comment: @lulu Yaaay! I know the stars and bars method ;)

Comment: In that case, try to correct the posted solution of @narekBojikian below.  That is very close to the correct answer but, as it currently stands, it isn't exactly right.  Applying Stars and Bars correctly does give the right answer.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry for mentioning you, but you are a good person with experience and I hope you can help me. Could you please check my reasoning answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $n!$ permutations of students.
Now lets take a permutation $i_1, i_2, .., i_n$ we want to distribute it in 4 slots. That means we have n-1 positions at which we can cut the set and we need to cut it at three of them, so the answer is

$n! * {n-1 \choose 3}$

P.s. no partition will be empty because the first cut is after the first element, the last one is before the last, and there is one element between any two consecutive  cuts

Comment: I assume $i=n$?  Also, don't forget that you need somebody on each bench.

Comment: You're right sorry, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: You are close, here, but not correct.  If you take $n=5$ and $k=4$ (as in the OP's question) you'll see that your text gives the correct answer but your formula does not.

Comment: @lulu so it would be $ n+k-1 \choose k $ multiplied by $n!$ ??

Comment: I think I've got it

Comment: The edited version is good. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on exactly what is meant by "with order."  If we take it to mean that both the order of the benches and the order in which people sit on each bench matter, then the answer is simple:

$$n!{n-1\choose3}$$

That is, line the people up from left to right, in any of $n!$ ways, then pick $3$ "break points" to decide which groups go to benches $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let k = number of benches = 4

It is like we are distributing people to benches. If there were no restrictions, then it would have been $${n+4-1\choose 4-1}$$

Since we have a rule that each bench should have at least one person, then $$ x1+....+xn = 4$$

For any pair of positive integers n and k, the number of distinct k-tuples of positive integers whose sum is n is given by the binomial coefficient
$xi∈Z,xi>0$
$${(n-k)+k-1\choose k-1} = {(n-4)+4-1\choose 4-1}$$

$$= {n-1\choose 4-1} == {n-1\choose 3} $$

The order matters, so we will need to multiply this by n! which is the arrangements that people could be seated.

Final answer: $$ n! \times {n-1\choose 3} $$

Now we are done solving this question by using the stars and bars method.

Comment: Completely sound.  (+1)